# Generate xslt from sql server database view

Tags: sql-server, xslt

Is there an easy way to generate xslt transform script from an existing database view? Need it to replicate view on other database.

Comment: Do you have to use xslt?  The standard way would be to script the view as a create statement using SQL.

Comment: Was trying to come up with a standard that was database independent, to transfer between different vendors.

Comment: The standard solution for that is to script a `CREATE VIEW` statement that uses no vendor-specific constructs. Although no database system exactly implements ANSI SQL, they all implement something close enough to it that you can get pretty far.